# Unmock function after mockimplementation

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm having a bit of trouble unmocking a function.

I first mock it and now I can't unmock it

```
//myClass.js
class myClass {

    static check(v1,v2) {
        return v1 > v2;
    }

    static async getinfo(v1,v2) {
        if (this.check(v1,v2)) {
            return await get('api.google.com');
        }
        return [];
    }
}


//myclass.spec.js
describe('Testing myClass', () => {
    describe('testing processing', () => {
        it('should return result', () => {
              const mockPatch = jest.fn().mockImplementation((version, solution) => false);
              myClass.check = mockCheck;
              try {
                const result = await myClass.getinfo(1,2);
                expect(result).toBe.([]);
              }catch(e) {
                throw e;
              }
        })
    })
    describe('Testing check', () => {
        it('should return true', () => {
            expect(myClass.check(2,1)).toBe.true
        })
    })
})
```

I already try with

`myClass.check.mockRestore()`

`beforeEach(() => {myClass.check.mockRestore()})`

`jest.unmock('./myClass.js)`

Is there anyway I can solve this? I read all the jest doc and i couldn't find anything

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do in your test? I suspect there's a better approach than what you're hoping to do here 

Comment: I wanna unit test the posible responses of `check` function. What do you think I should be doing¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods should never be mocked by reassigning them, there is no way how Jest could restore their original implementation this way.

This should always be done with `spyOn`:

```
jest.spyOn(myClass, 'check').mockReturnValue(false)
```

This way a method can be restored with `restoreMock` or `restoreAllMocks`. This should be preferably enabled globally in [Jest configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#restoremocks-boolean).

Comment: First I tried with the restoreMock in the same test and it didn't work but then in the cfg file it worked correctly. Ty!

Comment: If `restoreMock` is not available, Check `mockRestore`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you're hoping to do is to mock an implementation for use in a specific test, but then have your other tests function without the mocking.

If so, I think you could use the [module mocking strategy](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules) in conjunction with [mockReturnValueOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-return-values).

Be sure to import your module at the top of your tests, then to call `jest.mock` with the same path. After that, you should be able to call `myClass.check.mockReturnValueOnce`, and it will be mocked until the next time it is called. After that, it will function normally

Comment: this is mocking all the module, and now I get that `myClass.getinfo is undefined` when doing the first test